# How to make NFA remember its first step?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I have to design an NFA that will take the strings `"token"` and `token`.

I can use $\lambda$ or `"` to the first state, but then how do I know on the final state if it should have end quotes or not?

Comment: Note that an automaton for any finite set of strings is trivial: just have one linear chain per string. Therefore, I read the question such that `token` is an infinite set of possible token strings.

Answer (score 2):

NFAs have finite "memory", and you need to store one bit of information: whether the first symbol was `"`.

> Copy the automaton for tokens. If your string starts with `"`, move to one copy; if not, to the other. The first copy then requires a trailing `"` to accept, the second one does not.
>
>  In general, you can implement any finitely-bounded counter like this: just copy all states as many times as you need.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is the following. Suppose you NEA $N$ that accepts all `token` is the tuple $(Q,\Sigma,\delta,q_0,F)$. You build a new NEA $N'$ where you introduce for every state $q\in Q$ a copy. This can be encoded by defining as new state space as $Q':=Q\times\{\text{orig},\text{copy}\}$.

We interpret the new states as follow. If you are in some state $(q,\text{orig})$ then the text started, without `"` otherwise, if you are in some state $(q,\text{copy})$, the text started with `"`.  Now you have to add the transitions. The start state of $N'$ is $(q_0,\text{orig})$ and you can go with an `"` from that state to $(q_0,\text{copy})$. Otherwise it is not possible to traverse between the copied states and the original states. I think from here on you can figure out how to wire the rest of the NEA. One final remark you need $|F|$ additional states that ensure that the last character in the `"`-part ends with a `"`.